# Prove or disprove that if a|(sb+tc) for all (and for some) s,t ∈ ℤ, then a|b, and a|c.

Tags: proof-writing

So, this is actually 2 questions in 1. I apologize if that is bad practice, but I didn't want to write 2 questions when they're a word different. So, I have

1. Prove or disprove that if $a|(sb+tc), \forall s,t \in\mathbb{Z}$, then $a|b$, and $a|c$.

and then,

2. Prove or disprove that if $a|(sb+tc)$ for some $s,t \in\mathbb{Z}$, then $a|b$, and $a|c$.

I know how to prove if $a|b$ and $a|c$, then $a|(sb+tc),  \forall s,t \in\mathbb{Z}$, but I'm certain I can't just write the proof backwards, and show that it works. So, how would I tackle these two problems, especially the second one?

Comment: Note that the second proposition implies the first. So *a priori*, we know it's not possible for the second to be true *and* the first to be false.

Comment: The "for all" in the first statement is a very strong condition; you can choose whichever $s$ and $t$ you want in order to somehow derive $a \mid b$ and $a \mid c$. You might notice that $sb+tc=b$ when $(s,t) = (1,0)$ and that $sb+tc=c$ when $(s,t) = (0,1)$.

Comment: The "for some" in the second statement is a very weak condition, so we should intuitively expect it to be false. A good way to approach "prove or disprove" problems in which you think the statement is false is to first look for a counterexample. With a bit of thought you should be able to find an easy counterexample. In general, if it's difficult to find a counterexample you might want to think about whether it actually is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What happens when one of $s,t$ is one and the other one is zero?
2. $2014| 2014 \cdot 1 + 2014 \cdot 3$ but $2014$ doesn't divide $1$ or $3$...

Answer (score 0):

1. True.

Choose $s = 0, t = 1$, then $a|c$, and choose $s = 1, t = 0$, then $a|b$

2. False.

Let $a = 2, b = 3, c = 5$, and $s = t = 2$.